# How to seperate 2 pieces of concatinated JSONObject in 1 string? in Java (Android)

Tags: java, php, android

Yes, as question title. I got a single string received in android consist of 2 JSONObject.
I have to do 2 different processes in PHP but both result are returned (echo) in single string result which I don't know how to seperate it.
I'm using :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
String success = json.optString("success");
// "success" here shows empty in logcat. I think it doesn't get the second json object
```

Example of Result string:

```
{"username":"xx","activated":"0"}{"multicast_id":xxx,"success":0,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"xxx"}]}
```

How can I do?
(btw 2nd string is Firebase Cloud Messanging result example. 
**EDIT**: I'm using PHP to send FCM, that's why the result is forced to return together with my other string result even I do not (PHP::echo) it)

Comment: You need to combine and encode them properly in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` with proper `regex`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
    String response = "{\"username\":\"xx\",\"activated\":\"0\"}{\"multicast_id\":xxx,\"success\":0,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"xxx\"}]}";

    String[] separated = response.split("\\}\\{");

    String str1 = separated[0] + "}";
    String str2 = "{" + separated[1];

    Log.d("STRING", "String1: " + str1 + "\nString2: " + str2);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/STRING: String1: {"username":"xx","activated":"0"}
          String2: {"multicast_id":xxx,"success":0,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"xxx"}]}
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` with proper `regex`.

**AND**

Use this [website](http://www.txt2re.com/) to reveal the mystery of regexp